# Run a Local file system directory as input of a Mapper in cluster

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I gave an input to the mapper from a local filesystem.It is running successfully from eclipse,But not running from the cluster as it is unable to find the local input path saying:input path does not exist.Please can anybody help me how to give a local file path to a mapper so that it can run in the cluster and i can get the output in hdfs

Answer (score 6):

This is a very old question. Recently faced the same issue. 
I am not aware of how *correct* this solution is it worked for me though. Please bring to notice if there are any drawbacks of this.Here's what I did.

[Reading a solution from the mail-archives](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hadoop-general/200910.mbox/%3C95f8b1a90910132317h87df034nf59b8a3c69cc0b9c@mail.gmail.com%3E), I realised if i modify `fs.default.name` from `hdfs://localhost:8020/` to `file:///` it can access the local file system. However, I didnt want this for all my mapreduce jobs. So I made a copy of `core-site.xml` in a local system folder (same as the one from where I would submit my MR jar to `hadoop jar`).

and in my `Driver`  class for `MR` I added,

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.addResource(new Path("/my/local/system/path/to/core-site.xml"));
conf.addResource(new Path("/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/conf/hdfs-site.xml"));
```

The `MR` takes input from local system and writes the output to `hdfs:`

Comment: I have a 3 node cluster.I want to read file from local filesystem of machine 1.How can I do this>?

Answer (score 3):

Running in a cluster requires the data to be loaded into distributed storage (HDFS). Copy the data to HDFS first using `hadoop fs -copyFromLocal` and then try to trun your job again, giving it the path of the data in HDFS

Comment: But if i want to give the local file as the input of the map-reduce through a java program,then how should i specify it in the java program so as to run it in the cluster?

Comment: After you upload the file to HDFS, you then configure it in your Driver code using the input format's utility method, such as `TextInputFormat.addInputPaths(job, "/path/to/file/in/hdfs");`

Answer (score 2):

The question is an interesting one. One can have data on S3 and access this data without an explicit copy to HDFS prior to running the job. In the wordcount example, one would specify this as follows:

hadoop jar *example*.jar wordcount `s3n://bucket/input s3n://bucket/output`

What occurs in this is that the mappers read records directly from S3.

If this can be done with S3, why wouldn't hadoop similarly, using this syntax instead of s3n

```
file:///input file:///output
```

?

But empirically, this seems to fail in an interesting way -- I see that Hadoop gives a file not found exception for a file that is indeed in the input directory. That is, it seems to be able to list the files in the put directory on my local disk but when it comes time to open them to read the records, the file is not found (or accessible).

Comment: Actually, having discussed this, the answer is not that the data must first be in HDFS but simply that Hadoop mappers have no way to grab the records present in the local files; there is no server necessarily running on the local machine and no way of specifying the server to Hadoop.

Answer (score 0):

The data must be on HDFS for any MapReduce job to process it. So even if you have a source such as local File System or a network path or a web based store  (such as Azure Blob Storage or Amazon Block stoage), you would need to copy the data at HDFS first and then run the Job.
The bottom line is that you would need to push the data first to to HDFS and there are several ways depend on data source, you would perform the data transfer from your source to HDFS such as from local file system you would use the following command:

$hadoop -f CopyFromLocal *SourceFileOrStoragePath* _HDFS__Or_directPathatHDFS_

Comment: But if i want to give the local file as the input of the map-reduce through a java program,then how should i specify it in the java program so as to run it in the cluster?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the input path like this

FileInputFormat.addInputPath(conf, new Path(file:///the directory on your local filesystem));

if you give the file extension, it can access files from the localsystem

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the following code and got the solution...
Please try it and let me know..

You need to get FileSystem object for local file system and then use makequalified method to return path.. As we need to pass path of local filesystem(no other way to pass this to inputformat), i ve used make qualified, which in deed returns only local file system path..

The code is shown below..

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.getLocal(conf);
Path inputPath = fs.makeQualified(new Path("/usr/local/srini/"));  // local path

FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, inputPath);
```

I hope this works for your requirement, though it's posted very late.. It worked fine for me.. It does not need any configuration changes i believe..

Comment: util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not implemented by the DistributedFileSystem FileSystem implementation

Answer (score 0):

U might wanna try this by setting the configuration as

```
Configuration conf=new Configuration();
conf.set("job.mapreduce.tracker","local");
conf.set("fs.default.name","file:///");
```

After this u can set the fileinputformat with the local path and u r good to go