# Fastest way to upload text files into HDFS(hadoop)

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, hdfs

Iam trying to upload 1 million text files into HDFS. 
So, uploading those files using Eclipse is taking around 2 hours.
Can anyone please suggest me any fast technique to do this thing.?
What Iam thinking of is  : To zip all the text files into a single zip and then upload that into HDFS and finally using some unzipping technique , I would extract those files onto HDFS.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the source location?

Comment: Iam currently running Hadoop in single node cluster . So source of all those files is my local machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Distcp is a good way to upload files to HDFS, but for your particular use case (you want to upload local files to a single node cluster running in the same computer) the best thing is not to upload the files to HDFS at all. You can use localfs (`file://a_file_in_your_local_disk`) instead of HDFS, so no need to upload the files.

See this other [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10107665/run-a-local-file-system-directory-as-input-of-a-mapper-in-cluster) for examples on how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Try **[DistCp](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.19.0/distcp.html)**. DistCp (distributed copy) is a tool used for large inter/intra-cluster copying. It uses Map/Reduce to effect its distribution, error handling and recovery, and reporting. You can use it to copy data from your local FS to HDFS as well.

**Example : bin/hadoop distcp file:///Users/miqbal1/dir1 hdfs://localhost:9000/**

Answer (score 0):

If it is on your device, you can use the following command

hadoop fs -put <local_file_path><hdfs_directory_path>