# hadoop cluster use HDFS as default.fs, Client wants to use file on local file system

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, cloudera, hortonworks-data-platform

My hadoop cluster is using HDFS as default fs. But on client side, the input file is located on local file system. (for some reason, I don't want to move that into HDFS). If I give mapreduce job a Uri like 'file:///opt/myDoc.txt', I've got a file not exists error. How can I get access to local file system in this case?

Answer (score 0):

This is the place where you give the details of input path
**FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));**

Instead of args[0], give local path.
possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10107665/run-a-local-file-system-directory-as-input-of-a-mapper-in-cluster)