# Pig store fails to run store command when it is called using java code (embedded mode)

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am learning Hadoop, I tried running my pig script using java but it seems like it skips the store command written in the script and does not produce the output data file at the particular location.

But when I try running the pig script using command line, it gives the output data file as desired.

First I thought that java might have some permission issues that it is not creating a file. But I tried creating a file in the exact location using java and it easily creates an empty file. So it doesn't seem to be a permission issue.

Can anybody tell me what is the issue here that pig script runs successfully when used through command line but fails in the embedded mode?

Java Code:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;
import org.apache.pig.PigServer;

import java.io.IOException;

public class storePig  {



    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        try {
            PigServer pigServer = new PigServer("local");
            runQuery(pigServer);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void runQuery(PigServer pigServer) throws IOException {
        pigServer.registerScript("/home/anusharma/Desktop/stackoverflow/sampleScript.pig");
    }

}
```

Pig-Script:

```
Employee = LOAD '/home/anusharma/Desktop/Hadoop/Pig/record.txt' using PigStorage(',') as (id:int, firstName:chararray, lastName:chararray, age:int, contact:chararray, city:chararray);

Employe = ORDER Employee BY age desc;

limitedEmployee = LIMIT Employe 4;

STORE limitedEmployee into '/home/anusharma/Desktop/stackoverflow/output' using 
 PigStorage('|');
```

Comment: Does this file `file:/home/anusharma/Desktop/stackoverflow/output/part-r-00000`exist?

Comment: No this should be created after pig script executes.

Comment: Then why is it expected to be loaded as input?

Comment: Actually the output of the pig script is the input for my MapReduce job. So Mapreduce is showing the error that it cannot find the input file.

Comment: Did the `runQuery` method execute? Are there any logs for it?

Comment: yeah the control goes in the pig script..I checked it by using the describe command inside the pig script and it does show the output on the command line.

Comment: If it has executed, it must have generated the output file which is being read by the MR. But earlier you mentioned that the file does not exist.

Comment: No that is the problem, it is not generating any output file but if I run the pig script from the command line then the output of pig is created which is used by MR and hence no error comes..but when I try executing pig through java code then the output file( which is input for MR) is not created.

Comment: Try looking on how and where the job is run either local or yarn(map reduce).
PigServer pigServer = new PigServer("local");
As per code, you are trying to run the pig server in local mode but is java code able to load input file and is it running fine? Try dump Employee command. Hope you are using pig -x local while runing command line and using the same input file(local or hdfs) for map reducejob.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10107665/run-a-local-file-system-directory-as-input-of-a-mapper-in-cluster